# adding ssh public key to server by another user

Tags: ssh, server, ubuntu-14.04, public-key, ubuntu-server

i have the permission to ssh into the server but i want to add another persons public key on to the server so that he can also ssh into the server how can i do that ... i tried using the following command

```
<entered another users public key> | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

i get this error

```
 w: No such file or directory
```

but this command does not work fine for me... how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need `echo`:

```
echo "<entered another users public key>" \
    | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```